# How can I get this permalink structure?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

http://qz.com/206259/a-brief-history-of-soccer-in-the-us-and-why-it-might-finally-have-found-its-place-in-the-american-psyche/

qz.com runs on wordpress and uses a unique permalink structure I've never seen before.

Wordpress can use sitename.com/?p=123 (ie. post ID) or various other structures like date - d/m/post-name etc.

What qz.com seem to be doing is using the ID as the base url (guessing) then the post ID's slug after it, how are they doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little reading I found you can do it this way. /%post_id%/%postname%/